# using different key for to_json :methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

When using `:methods` in `to_json`, is there a way to rename the key? I'm trying to replace the real id with a base62 version of it, and I want the value of `base62_id` to have the key `:id`.

```
@obj.to_json(
    :except => :id
    :methods => :base62_id
)
```

I tried to do

```
@obj.to_json(
    :except => :id
    :methods => { :id => :base62_id }
)
```

but that didn't work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `to_json` serializer uses the name of the method as the key for serialization. So you can't use the `methods` option for this.
Unfortunately `to_json` method doesn`t accept`block` parameter, otherwise you could have done something similar to

```
@obj.to_json(:except => :id) {|json| json.id = base62_id }
```

So that leaves us with a ugly hack such as:

```
def to_json(options={})
  oid, self.id  = self.id, self.base62_id(self.id) 
  super
ensure
  self.id = oid
end
```

Now `to_json` will return the expected result.